# How to send multiple parameters from kendo data source read operation to WebApi controller

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following scenario: I have a kendo.dataSource which is populated via read request to a WebApi Controller. In addition to the read, I am sending a couple of parameters, which then I use in my controller to do some server logic. I was able to send as many simple parameters as I want via the parameterMap property of the transport function. Till now it was a simple get request. However now I need to send additional json object to the controller as a parameter. I read that I have to transform the Get request to Post and put the Json onto the body of the request but I don't know how to do it.

The code that I have so far:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: 'odata-v4',
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: wave.alarmsAndEvents.api('api/alarmsAndEventsSearch/post'),
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    SearchModel: JSON.stringify(vm.searchModel)
                },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',

            },

            parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                if (operation === "read") {
                    data.startDate = kendo.toString(vm.selectedTimeInterval.start, "G");
                    data.endDate = kendo.toString(vm.selectedTimeInterval.end, "G");
                    data.alarmsToDisplay = vm.maxRecords;
                }
                return kendo.stringify(data);
            }
        },
        pageSize: vm.maxRecords,
        error: function (e) {
            alert(e.xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The `SearchModel` is the thing that I want to send as `JSon`. The rest are simple `DateTime` and `int` parameters.

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IQueryable<AlarmsSearchViewModel> Post(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int alarmsToDisplay, [FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
    {
        ....
        return something;
    }
```

I end up with `Not Found 404`, but I am pretty sure that I have messed up the parameters. And from the Network window I can see that the json object is not sent at all. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you found your answer?

Comment: I think I had simply to create a model class in the backend to wrap up all of the parameters.